# Computer architecture - can I run a 64-bit OS?

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, 64-bit, 32-bit

I found this output from `lscpu` :

```
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 14
Stepping:              8
CPU MHz:               800.000
BogoMIPS:              3458.89
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              2048K
```

So, does it show that I have no hope for 64 bit linux OS?

Currently I am running a 32 bit OS (pretty happy with it), and when I tried to run a 64 bit version from a pen-drive my laptop stopped responding. So removed the pendrive, booted again & my 32 bit installed OS still runs fine. But my problem is, Google Chrome has dropped support for 32 bit Linux OS, so I am hoping to move to a 64 bit edition.

This laptop is in good condition and I don't want to replace it.

Answer (score 3):

Your CPU indeed does not support a 64-bit OS because there is no `64-bit` in `CPU op-mode(s)`.

If your only concern is that the 32-bit version of Google Chrome is unsupported and you are otherwise perfectly happy with 32-bit Ubuntu, then I suggest using the 32-bit version of Chromium, which is supported.

Comment: Yes, I have shifted to chromium, and firefox. I don't find any difference between Chrome & Chromium. Probably sites still using flash will display nothing. I have to check a lot now.